# In JavaFX & Scene Builder, how do I open a new window when clicking a button?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I've already got the FXML file for the second window, and I'm lost from here. How do I get my program to open the new window and FXML after I press a button?

This is how I have my first window set up

```
@Override 
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception { 
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml")); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root); primaryStage.setResizable(false);    
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!"); 
    primaryStage.show(); 
}
```

So I could copy that but change the values for my new window? Then how would I link that for my button? I've tried some Event handlers but to no avail.

Comment: Basically the same way you opened the first window... Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: This is how I have my first window set up

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
 {
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
  Scene scene = new Scene(root);
  
  primaryStage.setResizable(false);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
  primaryStage.show();
 }

So I could copy that but change the values for my new window? Then how would I link that for my button? I've tried some Event handlers but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know comments can't have code snippets, I will properly code this in an answer when my 8 hours limit is up

Comment: (I edited your question and added your code: go ahead and delete your comments to keep this cleaner.)

Comment: Can you show the code for the event handler you tried? You basically just create a new Stage and then do exactly what you do for your primary stage in the start method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FXML, on the button there is a property called onAction. You can find it on the "Code" section in scene builder, or directly on the .fxml file.
There you just type the name of a method.

Then, you need to create this method in the controller class of your scene. If you have not created a controller for your scene, you just need to set the property "controller" in your scene's root element, just like you did with the onAction of the button.

In the method you have created, you just type the code to open the new scene, something like this:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/org/yourcompanyname/yourapplicationname/layouts/nameOfYourFxmlFile.fxml"));
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
stage.setOpacity(1);
stage.setTitle("My New Stage Title");
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));
stage.showAndWait();
```